# Does .includes() run during a change detection loop if the variable associated with it does not change? / Alternative to .includes()

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if, front-end-optimization

I have a variable user_roles in my component file which gets initialized by an API on `ngInit()` and does not change after that.

```
this.service.getUserRoles().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.user_roles = data;
      }
    )
```

user_roles is an array which contains the permissions for that user : `user_roles = ['admin', 'mediator', ...]`

In my template I have code that displays components based on user_role:

```
<div *ngIf="user_roles.includes('admins') || user_roles.includes('mediator')">

    <div ....
    .
    . 
    .
```

Does .includes() run every time some other variable changes and the change detection loop runs? If it does, then what alternative can I use to improve performance?

Comment: One way to see it by yourself is to create a getter in the Typescript which does a `console.log` and use it instead of the direct variable in the template

Comment: Also one way to optimize is to compute the condition only once and store the result in a variable. I'm not convinced it will have that big of an impact in your example though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will.

`angular` change detection doesn't mean if a property changes, update its dependencies. That's actually the `vue` way. In reality `angular` change detection means everytime a async action(`Promise` `event` `setTimout`) happens, re-evaluate **every** template binding. So yes, `includes` will be called again.

The simplest way to verify is following

```
const orig = Array.prototype.includes
Array.prototype.includes = function<T> (arg: T) {
    console.log(this, arg)
    orig.call(this, arg)
}
```